# iDempiere multiple launching while updating any of OSGI plugins by Felix console

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, idempiere

I hope you can help me to solve the problem.

I’ve got a Linux server with **iDempiere 3.1** and **Java 1.8**. Only iDempiere schedulers are launched on this server. Each scheduler has its own launch frequency (start time). I noticed that while updating any of **OSGI plugins** by **Felix console**, time of the next launch of all the schedulers is upset. Moreover, it’s possible to launch a number of copies of the process (2, 3, 4 times etc), so I hаve the multiple launching. It looks like the scheduler is launched many times simultaneously as process copies.

Also I noticed that if I stop all the schedulers by `Stop All` button and then update any of OSGI plugins, the schedulers are launched automatically.

At the moment I have only one solution: after updating OSGI plugins I need to restart the iDempiere server. Of course it doesn't fit us.

I'm looking forward to hear from you any tips how I can solve it in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i really don't know whats your problem but if you want to run idempiere in tutorial you can see in [this link](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Developing_Plug-Ins_-_Setup_the_workspace)

First problem i can see just you run idempiere 3.1 and use java 1.8 actually your postgresql is it old version too? Match the version idempiere i prefer idempiere 5.1 if you use java 1.8 and use postgresql 9.5

And if you have old data in your database you can upgrade use migration script you can see in this [link](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Migration_Notes)